# Order by descending and returning the record number to use for ranking

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, ranking

I'm trying to rank users very simply by their reputation, which is stored as an `int` column in a MySQL table of users. In order to find out which users have the highest reputation from highest to lowest, I would do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY reputation DESC
```

Which would give me users ordered by highest reputation to lowest. Say user `Tim` shows up as the 3rd record. **How do I return which # record he is in that order, i.e his rank?** This seems really simple but I'm drawing a blank on how to do it. Essentially I want the record # after ordering to say "he is the user with the third highest reputation". Alternatively, is this the wrong way to go about ranking?

**I can specify a user in `users` by the column `user_id` and just mainly want to return the user's rank in one query, if possible.**

I'm using Laravel as a framework if anyone knows a shortcut using that, but just generally with SQL would be fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
set @rank:= 0;

SELECT (@rank:= @rank+ 1) AS Rank , users.* FROM users ORDER BY reputation DESC;
```

This will increment @rank for each resulting record.
For a specific user use:

```
SELECT T.reprank 
FROM   (SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS reprank, 
               users.* 
        FROM   users, 
               (SELECT @rank := 0) rnk 
        ORDER  BY reputation DESC) AS T 
WHERE  id = 23
```

Comment: I'm not sure.. what does that do? I'd basically just like to display next to the user's username what their rank is, determined by their reputation (i.e. if they have the third highest reputation, they are #3). I thought this would be super simple but I'm stuck.

Comment: Try it now I forgot table name on the select this should work

Comment: How do I then return the rank? That's the only piece I'm interested in. I'm looking to run a query that returns the # rank, which is calculated by descending reputation.

Comment: this will create a Rank column with everyone's rank. just try it and you'll see so you can return user's rank by id.

Comment: You can add SELECT Rank only and add WHERE user_id=2 for example this would return the rank of user 2

Comment: Sorry if I seem new, so this creates a temporary rank column, but then how do I query that temp column? This is admittedly beyond my SQL knowledge that's obvious..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42615/discussion-between-sam-d-and-wnajar)

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to the Sam D answer, but it puts everything into a single query:

```
SELECT
  @rank := @rank + 1 AS RepRank,
  users.*
FROM users, (SELECT @rank := 0) rnk
ORDER BY reputation DESC;
```

To limit results to a specific user you'll need to do an outer query - there's really no way around it. Here's how (note that the inner query is the same as the query shown above):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    @rank := @rank + 1 AS RepRank,
    users.*
  FROM users, (SELECT @rank := 0) rnk
  ORDER BY reputation DESC
) RankedUsers
WHERE User_ID = 5
```

Comment: How could I also return a user with `user_id = 5`'s rank in that one query? That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: You have to calculate the rankings first, then you can go ahead and pick `User_ID=5`. You can do that by surrounding the ranking query with an outer query. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: This still has an error, every derived table needs to have an alias. Oherwise, perfect.

Comment: Good catch, thanks! I've mostly been doing Oracle lately, and it doesn't require the alias. I've fixed the example.